# Best practice for accessing management port of firewall

Tags: network, linux, firewalls

I'm in the process of setting up a bunch of servers at the other end of the world (well, 8 hours travel time) in a co-location place.

The servers and firewall all have a remote management port (KVM, DRAC, you name it). I'm wondering what is the best practice how to access & secure that.

Obviously I could just put all those in a separate VLAN and put some filtering rules on the firewall (a Linux box). But then the accessibility of the firewall remote management depends on the firewall itself - I don't think this is a brilliant idea. One `ifdown` and you're out.

I could also just put the servers management ports into a separate net, and leave the firewall management port open on the internet, but this doesn't seem to be very elegant.

I could also leave everything on public internet, of course.

What are your recommended best practices?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the **bastion backdoor** architecture.

1. Install an hardened machine inside your remote network which will be
   used as a uniq entry point to access the inside of your remote network. For the clarity of this textual description I'll name it `bastion`.
   As a rule of thumb any protocol not used on `bastion` will have to be off.
   All allowed protocols will be logged (if possible on a `syslog` server within your remote network).
2. Put all your managment interfaces in a dedicated closed VLAN: `managment`. `managment` won't be accessible from the WAN or from the remote LAN. It will only be accessible from `bastion`.
3. Block any WAN direct access toward your firewall. Your firewall will only be accessible from `bastion` and through a very limited set of protocals (IPsec, ssh).

`bastion` will be a potential point of failure. In case of trouble on this
system, your remote network won't be accessible. If an attack on `bastion` turn successfull, the attacker will have control on your firewall and on all your managed server. Hence all your OS hardening should be done to make this
`bastion` as attack resistant and failure proof as possible.
I advise you to build it on top of any Unix which have a good reputation to permit the building of hardened OSes.

Comment: In fact that creates two points of failure: Both my firewall and bastion. If my firewall fails, I can't get to bastian any more as well.
I only allow protocolls that are needed anyway.

Comment: Right. I detailed the `bastion` point of failure because it is one **more** relative to your 1st solution which was already a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trade-off between usability and security. Never put your KVM or DRAC modules on the WAN, not long ago a nice exploit was released which targets [BMCs like DRAC](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2013/07/02/a-penetration-testers-guide-to-ipmi).

> Baseboard Management Controllers (BMCs) are a type of embedded
>   computer used to provide out-of-band monitoring for desktops and
>   servers. These products are sold under many brand names, including HP
>   iLO, Dell DRAC, Sun ILOM, Fujitsu iRMC, IBM IMM, and Supermicro IPMI.
>   BMCs are often implemented as embedded ARM systems, running Linux and
>   connected directly to the southbridge of the host system's
>   motherboard. Network access is obtained either via 'sideband' access
>   to an existing network card or through a dedicated interface. In
>   addition to being built-in to various motherboards, BMCs are also sold
>   as pluggable modules and PCI cards. Nearly all servers and
>   workstations ship with or support some form of BMC.

Considering DRAC  access is the same as having physical access to the machine:

> If I can physically access your device, it's not your device anymore

I would just go with making only the firewall accessible from the WAN and also protect it's login interface with IP filtering (your office only for instance) and add two-factor authentication to it.

The problem here is that you introduced a single point of failure. Normally you should at least have made the firewall redundant (which is not possible with Linux probably). So I would consider getting in some better hardware which can be placed in active-passive mode (or active-active if you want to load balance).

Comment: I must admit I fear user error more than failure. If the user send a wrong configuration to the firewall, usually the only option to get to it is via DRAC/KVM.
One way around is to issue a reboot before changing stuff and only making transient changes until they have prooven to be ok, but people tend to get lazy.
I see the point that all that DRAC stuff is probably not hardened enough, so I'll have to protect it behind a FW with some IP limiting...Damn ;)

Comment: IP limiting will not do you any good as IPMI uses udp...

Answer (score 0):

A locked down and isolated management LAN is the way to go. For OOB Access (Out Of Band Access, or getting into the admin network when the firewall is down) a hardened WAN-facing VPN server configured to ignore everything that isn't a secure VPN connection from a known IP (preferably the Disaster Recovery colo - you *do* have one of those, right?) is used to connect to the dead firewall and other infrastructure on the management network.

For instance - Your admins would use a VPN concentrator to connect to the DR site, and then access the Primary sites' management LAN over a site-to-site VPN connection. Depending on your budget, a private or MPLS circuit would be even more secure than WAN VPN access.

Without a DR site, direct access to the backup VPN server, such as admins on the road with an LTE connection or at home on a cable modem, is probably secure *enough* - for *most* purposes - with a suitably paranoid authentication scheme.